# Guess the picture password

Tags: knowledge, password

[image]This is my picture password as used in windows 10. I took the picture from my wallpapers and added some hints. I showed this to many people whom I believed to be able to solve it, but the only one that was close was a friend of mine who was a *Touhou* fan and also recently watched the Detective Conan episode *Ran's Suspicions*.

Comment: This is the original picture, but it looks the same to me... http://i.imgur.com/SYTPNRC.jpg

Comment: There are red boxes added.

Comment: A Windows picture password consists of a bunch of gestures on the screen; are we supposed to guess these gestures, or a traditional alphanumeric password?

Comment: I added the boxes you noticed (and one more crucial thing), so that you know where to tap. In my case the gestures are just tapping a spot. (fyi, there are not more than 3 allowed by windows). There is a lot you have to know to figure this out, but Wesley Situ has collected almost all you need.

Comment: Sakuya (3rd girl) is also underlined.

Comment: Heck, I'm just glad I'm not the only fan of Touhou here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Updated answer. For the picture password:

> Tap the squares next to 3, 9 then 8.

Because

> The character **Sakuya** is underlined. You can break up her name into three sounds: SA, KU, YA. Those syllables sound like the corresponding digits in Japanese: 3 (san), 9 (kyuu), 8 (hachi / See below for it's connection with "ya")

For reference for people who aren't too familiar with Touhou and Japanese

> **Numbers**
>  1 - ichi
>  2 - ni
>  3 - san
>  4 - yon / shi
>  5 - go
>  6 - roku
>  7 - nana / shichi
>  8 - hachi
>  9 - kyuu
>
>  **Characters**
>  1 - Hakurei Reimu (I don't see a relationship between her name and 1)
>   One of the main playable characters, boss in Imperishable Night (8th game, stage 4)
>
>  2 - Chen (She says "Nyaa" which has the "ni" sound in it)
>   Boss in Perfect Cherry Blossom (7th game, stage 2)
>
>  3 - Izayoi Sakuya (I don't see a relationship between her name and 3)
>   Boss in Embodiment of Scarlet Devil (6th game, stage 5)
>
>  4 - Konpaku Youmu (She says "Myon" which has the "yon" sound in it)
>   Boss in Perfect Cherry Blossom (7th game, stage 5)
>
>  5 - Alice Margatroid (She says "Gossun" which has the "go" sound in it)
>   Boss in Perfect Cherry Blossom (7th game, stage 3)
>
>  6 - Kamishirasawa Keine (Not sure about the relationship with 6)
>   Mid-stage boss in Imperishable Night (8th game, extra stage)
>
>  7 - Remilia Scarlet (Not sure about relationship with 7, but 7 is written the same way as "ku" in katakana)
>   Boss in Embodiment of Scarlet Devil (6th game, stage 6)
>
>  8 - Yakumo Yukari (The "Ya" in "Yakumo" is the same character as 8)
>   Boss in Perfect Cherry Blossom (7th game, phantasm stage)
>   Maybe relevant, but Yakumo Ran is the boss to the extra stage
>
>  9 - Cirno (Pronounced Chi-ru-no, 9 comes from the game's user manual depicting her easy mode spellcard that can be beat by just standing in front of her)
>
>   **Connection to Ran's Suspicions**
>   The episode connects a word to a passcode. Specifically, **Sherlock** becomes 4869, which can translate to "shi-ha-ro-kyuu", sounding like "Sherlock"

Comment: It is not 123456789. Reimu: Player 1, Sakuya: "Sa". She could also be "10" because the character for 10 appears in her name. Keine's is a reference to one of her lines, I think.

Comment: Yes, well done :)